# Access number that corresponds to string

Tags: c++

Let's say I have the following variables:

```
int number1 = 2;
int number2 = 4;
...
int numbern = 43;
```

Now what I want is to access these elements in a for loop over number 'i', so something like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  if(number1 == someFunc("number" + to_string(i)))
  {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Here 'someFunc' should make sure that it recognizes that I want to use the number that the string corresponds to. How could I do this?

Comment: Use an array instead.

Comment: Use std::map to connect the string "number1" to 2 and so on.

Comment: @a_guest Could you show me how that would be done?

Comment: @AndrewArnold Possible indeed, but there must be another way.

Comment: C++ doesn't have [type introspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) so it's not possible to access a variable if you have the name of it in a string. Using e.g. [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) as suggested by @a_guest is one possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using std::map you can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
map<string,int> mymap;

mymap["number1"] = 2;
mymap["number2"] = 4;
/* ... */

char number[2];
number[1] = '\0';
for(int ii=1; ii<=2; ii++)
{
    number[0] = (char)(ii+48);
    cout << string("number")+string(number) << ": ";
    mymap[string("number")+string(number)] += 1;
    cout << mymap[string("number")+string(number)] << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Here is the string the key through which you can access the actual number. In this example I didn't ensure that the key actually exists anyway this should be done normally.

Comment: The method here I used to create the key works of course only for 1 digit numbers. There are other ways to convert a number to a string you should use one of them. If you use C++11 you can simply use to_string(any number).

Comment: Thanks for your help! Why exactly do you have the "+48"? Actually, I don't fully understand what you do with the character statements. Could you please explain a bit more what happens around the for loop?

Comment: First of all I want to convert the 1 digit number to a char. For that I use the ASCII code of the digits (0 -> 48, 1 -> 49, ...; just search for ascii-table you"ll find one). That means for example: (char)48 = '0', i.e. gives me zero as a char. The constructor of class string now takes a char* which is pointing to the "c_str" which should be converted to string. For that the c_str must include a terminating char ('\0') so the constructor can know when he reached the end of the string.
In the end I have effectively "0\0" or "1\0", ...where '\0' denotes the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of the following two options:

1. Use an array.

   ```
   int numbers[] = {/* Put the initialization data*/};

   ....

   if(number1 == someFunc(numbers[i]))
   ```
2. Use a map. This option is useful if the size of the array is open to change or the key is expected to not follow the usual array index values.

   ```
   std::map<int, int> numbers;
   // Add code to initialize the map.

   ....

   if(number1 == someFunc(numbers[i]))
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Could you please elaborate on the map option?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I meant to use `std::map<int, int>`. This is only going to be useful if the size of the array is open to change or the key is expected to not follow the usual array index values.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of numbers is not big then you can write

```
int i = 0;

for ( int x : { number1, number2, /* other numbers */ numbern } )
{
   if ( x == someFunc( "number" + to_string( i ) ) )
   {
      // do stuff
   }

   ++i;
}
```

Otherwise you should place the numbers in some container.